# Simplify “Status Update Frequency”

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I need to measure if someone sends status updates about their current activity.

The best I came up with was “Status Update Frequency”.

Does this describe that measurement? Is there a simpler term? (I'm not a native English speaker.)

Comment: sounds understandable to me...

Comment: .......'contact log'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to know how frequent is the sending of status updates, you've thought of the best option, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the term, "**currency**":

> [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/currency): **currency**
>
> 4. The state of being current; up-to-dateness: 
>      *Can you check the currency of this address?*

For example, "Your TPS Report currency is bad, I need more frequent updates."